# File get contents not working properly

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using this file_get_contents for fetching external website html. but it is returning different output as compare to live one.

**ExternalUrl** : http://www.target.com/c/baby-baby-bath-bath-safety/-/N-5xtji#?lnk=nav_t_spc_3_inc_1_1

**My live code :** 
http://apptoplay.com/getImageUrl/file_get_contents.php

code

```
$url="http://www.target.com/c/baby-baby-bath-bath-safety/-/N-5xtji#?lnk=nav_t_spc_3_inc_1_1";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
```

**Edit:** Differences are in HTML. both are showing different totally different contents.

Comment: Differences in what is displayed in the browser and from file_get_contents are to be expected. Your browser is a different UserAgent than PHP. Responses to HTTP GET requests depend on the headers sent. Also, keep in mind that the browser will evaluate any JavaScript while PHP won't. If this doesnt already answer your question, please update your question to point out what the differences are instead of having us go to these sites.

Comment: edited the post. The difference is in HTML.

Comment: well, I guess we figured that much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to tell cURL to accept cookies.

Try this:

```
<?php
/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.target.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* STEP 3. visit cookiepage.php */
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.target.com/c/baby-baby-bath-bath-safety/-/N-5xtji#?lnk=nav_t_spc_3_inc_1_1");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $output = curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

[More description](http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/)